# How can i get items which are equal to string[]?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have an array of strings

```
var controlsToGet = new[] {"lblHome","lblContact"};
```

I have `List<LanguageControl>` and LanguageControl class holds Controls in it.
I want to get Controls from List which `Control.Name == controlsToGet`

I am looking for something like that

```
var all = fooelements.where(l=>l.Control.Name == controlsToGet);
```

Is it possible with lambda or linq.

*Note: I was able to do it with Nhibernate's Disjunction, i am looking for something like that*

**EDIT :** What would i do if i want to use this query for data base with the Entity Framework ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var all = fooelements
              .Where(l=>controlsToGet
                            .Contains(l.Control.Name));
```

---

If each item has a *list* of controls:

```
var all = fooelements
              .SelectMany(l => l.Controls)
              .Where(c => controlsToGet
                             .Contains(c.Name));
```

Comment: Thank you, i don't have much exp with lambdas.
Now, i got the way how to handle it

Comment: I short lambda could be great to ... var result = fooelements.FindAll(item=> controlsToGet.Contains(item.Name));

Comment: I don't mind the lose in reputation, but I wish whoever has downvoted had posted a comment. I'd be interested in knowing what was wrong with this answer even if it was only to help me educate myself...

Comment: +1 Harris, am i able to use it with Entity framework ? I have tried it and it didnt work

Comment: Sorry, I've never used the Entity Framework. If there is a specific issue with this code and the Entity Framework you may be best asking a new question with some code samples of exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the findall. If microsoft optimise the method you will increase performance, if not it's will be the same as the foreach

```
var result = fooelements.FindAll(item=> controlsToGet.Contains(item.Name));
```

Answer (score 2):

If `controlsToGet` is a string, this will work:

```
var all = fooelements.SelectMany(l => l.Controls).Where(c => c.Name == controlsToGet);
```

However, if it's a `List<string>` you will need:

```
var all = fooelements.SelectMany(l => l.Controls).Where(c => controlsToGet.Contains(c.Name));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var all = from control in listofcontrols
          from toGet  in controlsToGet
          where toGet == control.name
          select control;
```

Answer (score 1):

A naïve solution such as:

```
fooelements.SelectMany(l => l.Controls).Where(c => controlsToGet.Contains(c.Name))
```

is **O(n*m)** where **n** is the number of controls, and **m** is the number of strings in your name array.  Some may argue that this is nitpicking and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) and ... (yadda yadda), but what the heck - just a little more code gives you an **O(n)** solution:

```
var controlsToGet = new HashSet<string> { "lblHome", "lblContact" };
var controls = fooelements.SelectMany(l => l.Controls)
    .Where(c => controlsToGet.Contains(c.Name))
```

Comment: Good point. Assuming there are enough comparisons to overcome the initial cost of making the hashes this should be a faster solution.

Comment: Yes, the main point being that you've eliminated a performance dependency on the number of control names (which will no doubt change).